# Trying to parse a string into a list in Python

Tags: python, string, parsing, design-patterns, split

So I have a string like so:

`pattern = "AAaa$$##"`

I want to parse it into a list so it outputs letter by letter, 
but I can't do `pattern.split("")` cause it gives an error.
Like this `pattern.split()` wont work either, it will just give
me back the same string but in a list instead.

I need it to give me a list like this: `["A", "A", "a", "a", "$", "$", "#", "#"]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strings are iterable in python, any specific reason why you want to convert it to a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do

`list(pattern)`

It creates a list. Save it to any variable and use it. See the [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) entry.

```
For instance, list('abc') returns ['a', 'b', 'c'] and list( (1, 2, 3) ) returns [1, 2, 3]
```

Although, you can just iterate over the strings like so

```
>>> for elem in testString:
        # Do Something
```

Test-

```
>>> pattern = "AAaa$$##"
>>> list(pattern)
['A', 'A', 'a', 'a', '$', '$', '#', '#']
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed my problems. I'm not very familiar with Python's API, I'm quite new to it.

Thank you once more.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> pattern = 'AAaa$$##'
>>> list(pattern)
['A', 'A', 'a', 'a', '$', '$', '#', '#']
```

But if you just want to outputs the string letter by letter, there is no need to parse it into a list. The string itself is a sequence.

```
>>> for letter in pattern:
...     print letter
... 
A
A
a
a
$
$
#
#
```